# Cauchy recursive sequense

Tags: cauchy-sequences

I am wondering if this sequence is a Cauchy one or not?

$X_{n+1}=\beta+\underbrace{k\cdot\sqrt{d}}_{\alpha}\cdot X_n$.

Here, $\beta=1$, $\alpha\in (0,+\infty)$, $X_0=1$, $k\in (0,1)$ and $d\in(0,+\infty)$.

I understand that it is defined over $\mathbb{R}$ as a Banach space. Hence, my ultimate goal is to see if the sequence is convergent.

Comment: Where is the sequence?

Comment: @Atbey Thanks for the hint. The question is now updated to have a suitable form of the sequence in question. Thanks for sharing the point of view in advance.

Comment: Hint: Can you identify the limit, assuming it exists? (Oh, and proving Cauchy property is not required at all, actually.)

Comment: @Did I could implement it in Matlab, as part of my modelling project. I see, it converges but theoritically I dont see it.

Comment: @Did , Note: The sequence is a bit expanded to its original form.

Comment: @Did , I am wondering why Cauchy proof is not needed.

Comment: Because of the very precise and specific approach I outlined in my first comment. Did you read it (the comment)? Did you try it (the method)? I mean, writing a proof, not "implementing in matlab" or whatever you could do to avoid doing the maths...

Comment: @Did , It is a bit hazzy for me. Please read me more in this direction.

Comment: OK, here is "more in this direction": `Hint: Can you identify the limit, assuming it exists?`

Comment: @Did ،Hmmmm.... If I assume the limi exist then my sequence should be non-decreasing and bounded. Then I need to prove them.

Comment: @Did , Identifying the limit in an analytical way could be done by approach followed by the user parsiad , namely converting the iteration scheme to a form that has a known solution. I am not sure if I understood your question properly.

Comment: Perhaps you did not even read it? Eight words and a comma...

Comment: OK. FYI, if you think the "answer" you posted below proves anything, by recurrence or otherwise, and if you give it to your TA as such, then be aware that you might be in for a violent reaction from them...

Comment: @Did , Among those 8 words I do not understand what do you meand by saying identify the limit. Do you mean solving analytically ti find the limit? Could you elaborate your question more precisely?

Comment: @Did ,Thans for the info. It was a great help.

Comment: Sorry but you explicitely stated you were not interested. One cannot slap people in the face (why delete your comment?) and then expect this attitude to have no consequences. The thing is in the hands of your TA now...

Comment: Again a comment deleted? What a nice attitude...

Comment: @Did ,All right. Once again for the helpful comment.

Answer (score 0):

You should always try writing a few terms of the sequence out:
\begin{align*}
X_{0} & =1\\
X_{1} & =\beta+\alpha X_{0}=\alpha^{\phantom{1}}+\beta(1)\\
X_{2} & =\beta+\alpha X_{1}=\alpha^{2}+\beta(1+\alpha)\\
X_{3} & =\beta+\alpha X_{2}=\alpha^{3}+\beta(1+\alpha+\alpha^{2})\\
\text{etc.}
\end{align*}
The above suggests
$$
X_{n}=\alpha^{n}+\beta\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\alpha^{k}
$$
(you can prove this by induction).

Now, the summation (from $k=0$ to $n-1$) is a [geometric series, which has a closed form solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula). If you plug that in, then you will have an expression for $X_{n}$ whose limit you can take.

Comment: I deeply appreciate the elabirated answer. It is a lot helpful. With this, I conclude that no Banach space as the background is needed to prove the convergence of sequence.

Comment: Feel free to accept if this answered your question. Were you able to get the answer from the hint?

Comment: Is it accepted now?

Comment: No, but it's not a huge deal. There's a checkmark you have to click to accept an answer.

Comment: Right but the problem is I do not see the check mark!

Comment: Might have to do with you being a new user. You might have to wait a certain amount of time before you can accept. Anyways, it's not a big deal. (More important that you understood the answer)

Comment: ,Exactly it is the first post. Thanks indeed. I'll do it.

Comment: Now I reach to the point that, if \alpha\in(0,1) then the sum as a geometric series converges to \frac{1}{1-\alpha}. So, I need to work on my \alpha and find the condition that makes the whole scheme convergent.

Comment: That's correct. You need $|\alpha| < 1$ to ensure convergence.

Comment: great support. I deeply appreciate.

Answer (score -1):

Let me please try to prove the raised induction part of the problem as$\colon$

Prove $X_n=\alpha^n+\beta\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{\alpha^k}$ for all $n\ge 0$.

We start by reformulating the problem so that we have$\colon$

Prove $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{\alpha^k}=\frac{X_n-\alpha^n}{\beta}$

We proceed by proof as$\colon$

- Induction basis$\colon$ In case $n=1$,

$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{\alpha^k}=\sum_{k=0}^{0}{\alpha^k}=\alpha^0=1$.

- Induction hypothesis: we assume in case $n\ge 0$,

$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{\alpha^k}=\frac{X_n-\alpha^n}{\beta}$

holds true.

- Induction step: we need to show:

$\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\alpha^k}=\frac{X_n-\alpha^n}{\beta}$

holds also true. In this direction, we take the left hand side of the latter equation and expand it as:

$\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\alpha^k}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{\alpha^k}+\sum_{k=n}^{n}{\alpha^k}$

or further as:

$\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\alpha^k}=\underbrace{\frac{X_n-\alpha^n}{\beta}}_{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{\alpha^k}}+\sum_{k=n}^{n}{\alpha^k}$

or,

$\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\alpha^k}-\sum_{k=n}^{n}{\alpha^k}=\frac{X_n-\alpha^n}{\beta}$

that could be simplified as:

$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{\alpha^k}=\frac{X_n-\alpha^n}{\beta}$

A final re-arrangement leads us to:

$X_n=\alpha^n+\beta\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{\alpha^k}$

that is true based on our induction hypothesis.